# refresh multiple classes every n secs from php backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some code in jquery that connects to php and refreshes the class with latest data. This is working ok. However, I need to update 3 classes and when it refreshses the values are empty.

Is there a way I can query db and update 3 classes with fresh data every n sec. Many thanks

js

```
// Update server with latest actions,destructions and return requests
    setInterval(function() {
      $.get('/domain/admin/refreshBox.php', function(data) {
      $(".actions").text(data);
      $(".retrievals").text(data);
      $(".returns").text(data);
      });
    }, 10000);
```

php

```
$sql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) as total FROM act WHERE new = '1'");
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $num = $rows['total'];
    //echo $num;
    $ni = $num;

    if($ni < 1) {
      $ni = '0';
    }
    echo $ni;

    $nisql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) as ni FROM act WHERE activity='New Intake' AND new = '1'"); 
    $niintknum_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nisql);
    $niintknum = $niintknum_row['ni'];
    //echo $num;
    $niintk_num = $niintknum;

    if($niintk_num < 1) {
      $niintk_num = '0';

    echo $niintk_num;

    $brtvsql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) as rtrv FROM act WHERE activity='Box Retrieval' AND new = '1'"); 
    $brtv_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brtvsql);
    $brtvnum = $brtv_row['rtrv'];
    //echo $num;
    $brtv_num = $brtvnum;

    if($brtv_num < 1) {
      $brtv_num = '0';

    echo $brtv_num;


    $brtnsql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) as brtn FROM act WHERE activity='Box Return' AND new = '1'"); 
    $brtn_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brtnsql);
    $brtnnum = $brtn_row['brtn'];
    //echo $num;
    $brtn_num = $brtnnum;

    if($brtn_num < 1) {
      $brtn_num = '0';
    }
    echo $brtn_num;
```

Comment: you want to echo 3 different values and make it update three different HTML elements with those values? You need to create a JSON array and return that from PHP so that the Javascript code can work out which value is which. Right now you just output a jumble of text.

Comment: You also have some strange pieces of code e.g. `$niintk_num = $niintknum;` and `$brtv_num = $brtvnum;` - what is the point of setting a variable to itself? This is completely useless code.

Comment: @ADyson Could you do example of this please. Many thanks

Comment: You can google any number of tutorials about creating JSON in PHP. But basically make a PHP object or array containing your values, and then transform it to JSON using json_encode() and echo that

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for that. I am fairly new to this level of scripting, but will give it a go. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson Those codes go in the header where they are displayed, `<li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Returns">Returns <span style="float: right;" class="notification returns"><?php echo $brtn_num; ?></span></a>
                  </li>`

Comment: @ADyson Works well if i use one class and one query

Comment: Sorry I don't follow how that code in your comment is relevant to the above? Is there some more PHP in the refreshBox.php script which you haven't shown? Are you trying to use the same script for loading the whole page and also making your ajax request? If so, don't.

Comment: @ADyson I have posted the code I am using. If I only use one query and one class in the $.get it works. Obviuosly it dosen't know where to put the data with the way I have coded it. Thanks

Comment: yes that's why you need to use JSON as I already mentioned. Have a go. If you get stuck, show me your updated code. What you're doing now just makes no logical sense.